# How much would firearms cost?

Tags: dnd-5e, pricing, firearms

Referring to the firearms listing on page 268 of the DMG and assuming this is a world where these types of firearms are common, how much would the firearms cost?

To clarify, in a world where the "Modern items" are common and the "Futuristic items" are extremely rare but exist (using the rarity system, futuristic items would either be rare or very rare, haven't quite decided yet). Price range around something where it would be reasonable for a level 1-5 PC to have at least one, maybe two if they really wanted it.

Comment: Is it your intention to balance the weapons based on their power, or based on "so a level 1-5 player can have at least one"? Because in the case of the latter, there seems to be no reason for any character to want anything other than a modern gun, and in the case of the former they'd probably be Rare+ rarity, because they outshine most magic items.

Comment: Are you asking as the DM running the game, or as a player?

Answer (score 2):

**Your firearms should cost as much as their ranged weapon equivalent.**
That is to say, if firearms exist in your world they either cost the same as typical equipment and are not stronger, or they cost more because they are significantly stronger.

My suggestion is that you make a ranged weapon (magical or mundane) that functions mechanically the same as you would want your firearm to function, and then use that items estimated price per the dmg.

Personally, I would recommend you decide how rare these pieces of technology be and go from there.

**Mundane Items** (1-100g) pretty much anyone they encounter thats anybody remotely important would be carrying (personally would be pistols and shotguns)

**Uncommon** (100-500) would be maybe seen frequently but not everywhere. (over 50%. personally would be automatic rifles, though I would give both a +1)

**Rare** (500-5000) would be modified versions of these. maybe a pistol with burst fire and +2, or check out players handbook for some magical properties you can re flavor (incendiary ammo maybe). Low percentage of people have these. Most of which are serious military types.

**Very Rare**(5000-50000) would start futuristic weapons (laser pistol, laser rifle, antimatter in its base state) A special forces division maybe has a stock of these. a couple scavengers stumbled upon some here and there. Most people have never seen one and aren't necessarily even able to articulate what they can do.

**Legendary** would be any very rare with any modifications. (50000-500000)
Legend says that a man named Jerry lives in the cannibal mountains. He learned how to make new technology thats wild and dangerous.

Personally, your level 1-5 players would probably not buy any of these futuristic weapons. They would stumble upon one, maybe.

So personally revolver probably 50g, pistol 75, shotgun rifle etc 100.
Advanced scope gives +1, boosts cost by 100 on a pistol/revolver and 200 on a rifle. maybe something like a grenade launcher on a rifle can cost upwards of 300.

Incendiary rounds, sabo rounds (pierce walls), night vision, heat vision boosts weapons costs upwards of +2k for a pistol, +3k for a rifle.

Laser Pistols (20k, laser rifles 25k, antimatter rifle 30k)
Any of those with modifications are easily 100k+

Comment: You might add something to the effect of "comparable rarity" to make this more complete.

Comment: This does not seem to address that the OP wants to use the firearms listed in the DMG, which have no comparable ranged weapon with a price (and are _way_ stronger)

Comment: Slagmoth, as far as I am aware their relative power will be similar to their relative rarity (properties are listed by rarity)

Comment: Erik, good point, rereading the section now. Considering though, I can only really offer best estimates.